# Write name of current song playing in mpg123 to file

Tags: linux, shell

I am coding together a script that will display the current song playing on my Raspberry on a HD44780 display. I got everything working except the part where I need to display the name of the song currently playing.

```
mpg123 -Z /mnt/usbflash/mp3/*  > /tmp/ramdisk/mpg123.output &
```

The above command will play the songs just fine, but it doesn't write the track info the the text file.. any ideas what is the best way to script this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run on one file at a time in a loop, and keep track of where you are in the loop.

```
for f in /mnt/usbflash/mp3/*; do
    echo "$f" >/tmp/currently-playing
    mpg123 -Z "$f" # maybe redirect stdout / stderr?
done &
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of a similar way only the file name might contain less information than the ID3 tags inside the file that are displayed when mpg123 starts playing the song..

Comment: Once you have the file name, you can extract its ID3 tags. And/or redirect the output from the individual `mpg123` instance instead.